# Flutter Text Field Prefix text Issue

Tags: flutter, textfield

Not able to align the prefix text along with the input text ?

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
              child: TextField(
                controller: amountController,
                maxLines: 1,
                textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(25),
                ],
                style:
                    const TextStyle(color: AppColors.textColor, fontSize: 14),
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  isDense: true,
                  prefixText: "\$",
                  prefixIconConstraints:
                      BoxConstraints(minWidth: 0, minHeight: 0),
                  labelText: AppStrings.transferAmount,
                  floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: AppColors.textColor),
                  floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: AppColors.primary,
                    ),
                  ),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: AppColors.borderColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  value = "\u0024 $value";
                },
              ),
            ),
```

[image]

Tried setting the gravity but it is not getting aligned with the input text

Comment: What do you exact want?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put text right after Prefix you need to change
`textAlign: TextAlign.end,` to `textAlign: TextAlign.start,`

If you want to just put $ sign before your input text use this `onChange`

```
onChanged: (value) {
          if (value.startsWith("\$")) {
            // if the string already starts with $, just use it as is
            amountController.text = value;
          } else {
            //If the string doesn't start with $, add it
            amountController.text = "\$" + value;
          }
          //Set the cursor at the end of the text
          amountController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
            TextPosition(offset: amountController.text.length),
          );
        },
```

The onChanged function does not modify the TextField's value directly. It only provides the current text. In your code, you're assigning a new value to a value, but this doesn't affect the TextField. To change the TextField's text, you should use a TextEditingController.

example:

```
// In your TextField
TextField(
  controller: controller,
  onChanged: (value) {
    controller.text = "\u0024 $value";
    controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
        TextPosition(offset: controller.text.length),
      );
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just hide/remove `textAlign: TextAlign.end` under `TextField` widget. You'll understand other things.

> **Update answer** - You Need -> $ 123 not -> 123 $ So,

Try this, Update your controller.

```
final TextEditingController amountController = TextEditingController(text: "\$");
```

Comment: Actually I need both the text and prefix text to be aligned to the end.

Comment: So why do you use prefix? Use suffix for the dollar sign.

Comment: Needed -> $ 123  not -> 123 $ so when I use the prefix it shows only at the start Text Field not at the start of the text.

Comment: Got it. I found an alternative way.  Try this, I've updated my code.

Comment: It shows the dollar initially only not after updating the value though.

Comment: Why do you need it after value? Do you've to pass the $ as a value also?